# Problem when making frontend and backend communicate

Tags: reactjs, nginx, kubernetes, backend, nginx-ingress

i'm working with Minikube to make a full stack K8s application using React as a frontend and ASP NET Core as a backend.
Here there are my configuration

Deployments and Services

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: web-frontend
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend-deployment
  labels:
    app: frontend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app:
          frontend
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: web-frontend
      containers:
      - name: frontend
        image: frontend
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend-svc
spec:
  selector:
   app: frontend
  ports:
   - protocol: TCP
     port: 80
     targetPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: backend
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend-deployment
  labels:
    app: backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app:
          backend
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: backend
      containers:
      - name: backend
        image: backend
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend
spec:
  selector:
   app: backend
  ports:
   - protocol: TCP
     port: 5000
     targetPort: 5000
```

Dockerfiles for the frontend

```
FROM node:alpine as build-image
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm i
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

This is instead my Ingress

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: frontend-backend-ingress
  annotations:
#    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: frontend-svc
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /api/?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: backend
                port:
                  number: 5000
```

However, when I type `minikube tunnel` to expose the ingress IP locally I can reach the frontend, but when the frontend tries to get a `fetch` request to `/api/something` in the browser console I get `GET http://localhost/api/patients/ 404 (Not Found)` and an error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`.

Moreover, If I change the Ingress in this way

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: frontend-backend-ingress
  annotations:
#    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: frontend-svc
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /api/
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: backend
                port:
                  number: 5000
```

Then I can issue `curl localhost/api/something` and I get the JSON result, but when the frontend tries to contact the backend I get

```
GET http://localhost/api/patients/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at main.358f50ad.js:2:473736
    at s (main.358f50ad.js:2:298197)
    at Generator._invoke (main.358f50ad.js:2:297985)
    at Generator.next (main.358f50ad.js:2:298626)
    at Al (main.358f50ad.js:2:439869)
    at a (main.358f50ad.js:2:440073)
```

This looks strange because if I try the frontend and the backend outside kubernetes everything works fine and from the React application the result from the backend is correctly fetched (of course using the `proxy` inside the `package.json`)

Answer (score 1):

To contact or make links between apps you could use their kubernetes native FQDN ( try to ping or telnet it if you want to test the connection but here is how it works:
Thr default FQDN of any service is:

```
 <service-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local.
```

In your above example, you should be able to contact you backend service from your frontend one with:

```
backend.YOURNAMESPACENAME.svc.cluster.local:5000
```

For services in same namespace, you don't need to use the FQDN to access services, just the service name would be enough:

```
backend:5000
```

I don't know where you exactly configure the links between the frontend and backend but however, you should "variabilize" this link and add the variable definition in kubernetes manifest.

Comment: Hi, sorry for being late.
I made some tests and also read that since this is a React application the code of the app is directly executed in the browser and so the requests are not made by the React App directly but by the browser itself, so that an Ingress is necessary in order to reach the backend pod.
As I said I made some test, If I try to `curl` the backend without an Authorization Bearer token everything works fine, but when I sent a valid token the backend crashes. I leave the log of the backend containers here https://pastebin.com/vatqDPzk.
The fact is everything works outside k8s!